# useEffect not triggering when object property in dependence array

Tags: reactjs

I have a context/provider that has a websocket as a state variable.  Once the socket is initialized, the onMessage callback is set.  The callback is something as follows:

```
const wsOnMessage = (message: any) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(message.data);
    setProgress(merge(progress, data.progress));
};
```

Then in the component I have something like this:

```
function PVCListTableRow(props: any) {
    const { pvc } = props;
    const { progress } = useMyContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Progress', progress[pvc.metadata.uid])
    }, [progress[pvc.metadata.uid]])

    return (
        {/* stuff */}
    );

}
```

However, the effect isn't triggering when the `progress` variable gets updated.

The data structure of the `progress` variable is something like

```
{
    "uid-here": 0.25,
    "another-uid-here": 0.72,
    ...etc,
}
```

How can I get the useEffect to trigger when the property that matches `pvc.metadata.uid` gets updated?

Or, how can I get the component to re-render when that value gets updated?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

> The function passed to `useEffect` will run after the render is
> committed to the screen.

And that's the key part (that many seem to miss): one uses dependency list supplied to `useEffect` to *limit* its invokations, but not to set up some conditions extra to that 'after the render is committed'.

In other words, if your component is not considered updated by React, `useEffect` hooks **just won't be called!**

Now, it's not clear from your question how exactly your context (`progress`) looks like, but this line:

```
setProgress(merge(progress, data.progress));
```

... is highly suspicious.

See, for React to track the change in *object* the reference of this object should change. Now, there's a big chance `setProgress` just assignes value (passed as its parameter) to a variable, and doesn't do any cloning, shallow or deep.

Yet if `merge` in your code is similar to `lodash.merge` (and, again, there's a huge chance it actually is lodash.merge; JS ecosystem is not that big these days), it doesn't return a new object; instead it reassigns values from `data.progress` to `progress` and **returns the latter**.

It's pretty easy to check: replace the aforementioned line with...

```
setProgress({ ...merge(progress, data.progress) });
```

Now, in this case a new object will be created and its value will be passed to `setProgress`. I strongly suggest moving this cloning inside setProgress though; sure, you can do some checks there whether or not you should actually force value update, but even without those checks it should be performant enough.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no problem... are you sure `pvc.metadata.uid` key is in the progress object?

*another point: move that dependency into a separate variable after that, put it in the dependency array.*

Comment: Yes, I am sure, as the result printed in the wsOnMessage when I do `console.log(merge(progress, data.progress))` shows me `{"aeccafaa-67fa-11ea-85c0-caa934b40d56": 1}`, which is the correct uid value.  Also, if I force a re-render by updating something else in the compoent, like the checkbox, it updates the progress bar based on the progress value.

Answer (score 0):

Spread operator create a new reference, so it will trigger the render

```js
let updated = {...property};
updated[propertyname] =value;
setProperty(()=>updated);
```

If you use only the below code snippet, it will not re-render

```js
let updated = property; //here property is the base object 
updated[propertyname] = value;
setProperty(()=>updated);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `[progress['pvc.metadata.uid']]`

```
function PVCListTableRow(props: any) {
    const { pvc } = props;
    const { progress } = useMyContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Progress', progress[pvc.metadata.uid])
    }, [progress['pvc.metadata.uid']])

    return (
        {/* stuff */}
    );

}
```

Comment: the `uid` is the object key, so you cannot use `progress['pvc.metadata.uid']` here.